# .NET Click Event (WinForms)

Tags: .net, events, click

I am building a minesweeper and was having difficulties with the mouse event. In the original Windows Minesweeper, the user may click and drag the mouse while pressing. The new tiles that the user enters while still pressing change to a cleared tile and the previous tile restores back to what it was if it was not clicked. On VB.Net, when I click and attempt to mouse over another tile while still pressing, the other tiles I am on do not appear empty like in the original minesweeper. Any idea on what I could do to fix this issue?

Sorry about that John Saunders, I am new at this site. Thanks for advising me.

Comment: I have already supplied the MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseEnter and MouseLeave to do some stuff. MouseDown tells the  program that a tile has been clicked and when mouse is up, then we perform a code which checks to see if the tile is a bomb and if you flag or win or lose. MouseEnter changes the tile picture and so does the MouseLeave. MouseUp also has some events with the pictures. 

The problem is that I cannot click and move the mouse on the tiles and get the same results as in the original Minesweeper.

Comment: Please do not use comments for this purpose. If you have more information, then edit your original question. Also, FYI, there is no VB.NET click event. There is a .NET click event, and you're writing your code in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply more details.
I've guessed your code structure and am answering based on my guesses.

You're probably handling the `MouseClick` event and toggling the tiles.

You need to handle the `MouseMove` event, and, if the mouse button was pressed (track this in `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`, set a variable that gets read in your `Paint` event to draw the tile.
You could also check the `MousePosition` property in the `Paint` event instead of handling `MouseMove`.